# Next.js Deployment Error - TypeError: Can't access property "user", "m" is undefined when using OAuth/Next.js signIn during deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, deployment, oauth

[image: Image of the error]
I'm encountering a peculiar issue while deploying my Next.js application. During the deployment process, I face an error message stating: "Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information)". However, when I run the application locally, the OAuth sign-in functionality works perfectly fine without any errors.

The specific error displayed in the browser console is: "TypeError: can't access property 'user', 'm' is undefined". It seems to be related to accessing the 'user' property during the sign-in process.

I'm using Next.js version 10 for my application. I have implemented OAuth sign-in functionality, which is working as expected in my local environment. However, it fails to work properly during deployment.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or potential solutions to resolve this issue and successfully deploy my Next.js application with OAuth sign-in. Are there any additional configuration or deployment steps that need to be considered in order to avoid this error?

Thank you for your assistance!